# Don't want to use Registry in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows

I want to remove registry dependency in my Windows service written in C#. and want to maintain Event Logs under Event Viewer under application.
I am using the below code which does not seem correct as I do not want to use Registry.

I am getting Source property was not set before writing to the event log.

Please advice.

```
public Service()
{           
    try
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if(!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("VWinService"))
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("VWinService","");
        eventLog1.Source = "VWinService";
        eventLog1.Log = "";     

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {               
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Error in Service Constructor.  Error message = " + ex.Message.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }
} 


 private void InitializeComponent()
    {       
        this.eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
        this.tmrSend = new System.Timers.Timer();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLog1)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.tmrSend)).BeginInit();
        this.tmrSend.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.tmrSend_Elapsed);
        this.AutoLog = false;
        this.ServiceName = "VWinService";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLog1)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.tmrSend)).EndInit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

An event source need only be defined once at installation time, an action that generally requires administrative privilege and is performed by your installer.  Once the event source exists, you can write event entries using just the source name.

Writing one error to the event log is:

```
EventLog eventLog = new EventLog();
eventLog.Source = "VWinService";
eventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error, 0);
```

The logic to create the event source

```
if(!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("VWinService"))
    System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("VWinService","");
```

belongs in an installer and need not be repeated in your service application code.  If you have created your service application using a Visual Studio wizard, then this is handled for you in autogenerated `ProjectInstaller` classes.

If you intend to use event logs and install your service, then there will necessarily be registry entries on Windows.  Creating these required registry entries is the responsibility of your software installer.  For example, see [InstallUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which uses the `ProjectInstaller` classes to install your service application.  Be assured that your client will understand and agree that registry settings created by an installer to register your application as a service and use the event log are normal and required for your application.

You should be able to entirely avoid using the registry for your *application* settings.  For simple configuration values, you can add entries in `app.config` like so:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myStringSetting" value="My string value"/>
    <add key="myNumericSetting" value="73"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Your code will use the `System.Configuration` namespace to read settings:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

You read the configuration values in your code like so:

```
string myString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myStringSetting"];
int myNumber = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myNumericSetting"]);
```

If the organization of the existing registry settings is much more complex, then you should create a [Custom Configuration Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Describing in detail how to do this is far beyond the scope of your original question.  Please refer to the documentation or create a new question.

Comment: Can you please eloborate it?

Comment: I want to use event logs without registry entry on windows. Is it Possible?

Comment: I want to use event logs without creating registry entry on windows. Is it possible? If yes then how? Also, I would really appreciate if you share me your Email -id so that I can share my code and you can advice me more. Thanks.

Comment: It is not possible.  The event log service uses the registry, and if you have a requirement to use the event log, then you must create the necessary registry entries.  See [Event Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363661(v=vs.85).aspx).  But the dependency on the registry can and should be isolated to your installer which can be made separate from your service application code.

Comment: You mean to say  for event log registry creation is must? Right? Pleas e let me know witout creating registry how we can maintain logs ? What are other ways to maintain logs and how to do that?

Comment: As you said the dependency on the registry can and should be isolated to your installer which can be made separate from your service application code.Will it use Registry concept or not?

Comment: in other words we can't use event log without using registery? is it?

Comment: Yes, an installer would use the registry.

Comment: If I dont want to use installer then is it possible?

Comment: I believe that I have answered your question.  Changing how you ask it will not change the answer.

Comment: I have a requirement to remove registry concept in existing window service and use application configuration file in case of all the values which is set in registry and as well as maintain Event Logs witout registry.

Comment: As I already informed client that this is possible so I am confirming again & again . As without creating registry, we are not able to maintain event logs so Could you please advice what should I advice to client now if this is not possible? I am so worried :( Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have revised my answer to address your concerns.

Comment: Please see the  above Service() constructer code. I am getting error as Source property was not set before writing to the event log. Could you please advice how do resolve this issue by using application config file.

Comment: Hi, Please share your email id.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid using the registry, either for event logs, or, in fact, for services themselves. You have misinformed your client. Your client should tell you why they think they don't want to use the registry.

If it were even possible, then your client would be the only ones in the world not to use the registry. The registry is an inherent part of Microsoft Windows, and has been for a very long time. Your client is no doubt misinformed about the registry, such that he thinks he wants to avoid it.

You will do your client the greatest favor by learning how Windows Services (and the event logs) use the Registry, then educating your client about that.

Comment: Hi Please share your email id

Comment: I did see the code, and that's why I advised you that this is not possible.

Comment: how can we maintain logs of my window service if this is not possible? Any another alternative?

Comment: Yes. Be brave and find out why the client feels that the Registry is not acceptable. Most likely, the client is simply confused about it.

Comment: Do you know what are the limitations when we use Registry in Windows service?

Comment: I don't know what you mean about restrictions. Every Windows Service in the World uses the registry. Please take the time to learn a little about Windows services and the registry. To be honest, your level of ignorance about the Registry makes it difficult for you to ask questions, and even more difficult for me to answer your questions.

Comment: I will share my code to your email id and then you can cross check the same and advice me about restrictions.

Comment: Pls provide me your Email id.

Comment: No, I'm done with this. You're not taking the advice I've been giving you - go learn about the Registry and then go educate your client or find out _why_ they want to not use the registry. For instance, maybe they are Unix people and have heard bad things about the registry so they don't want to use it.

Comment: Can we use Log4net  for logging?

Comment: You are completely missing my point so you will completely fail. **Every Windows Service Must Use The Registry**. Windows Services are _registered_ in the registry. It's the Registry that tells Windows which Windows Services to run. You cannot have a Windows Service without the Registry. Why am I even _talking_ to you when you **refuse to listen**?

Comment: ok Thanks for your valuable suggestion. I will inform client it's not possible to remove registry dependency from existing Window service.